# customize group header for kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

There's two fields 'number' and 'name' in my datasource which are 1 to 1 related.

Currently, I grouped the data using number field, and the group header display 'number: xxx'. Is there a way to append the name field behind the current text? As 'number: xxx, name: xxxx'?

I have checked the kendo grid documentation and searched a long time, it seems kendo grid only support show the group header based on the grouped field's value or aggreagates, couldn't find a solution to group as these two fields.

Then I have another solution to deal with it. Add a new field which combined the two fields, then group by this new field, but the new field will display in columns filter in the column header. Is there a way to solve this problem?

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "number",
        hidden: true
    },{
        field: "name"
    }, {
        field: "order"
    }],
    dataSource: {
        data: [{
          number: 1,
            name: "Jane Doe",
            order: "order1"            
        },
        {
          number: 1,
            name: "Jane Doe",
            order: "order2"            
        },
        {
          number: 1,
            name: "Jane Doe",
            order: "order3"            
        },{
          number: 2,
            name: "Allen",
            order: "order1"
        },{
          number: 2,
            name: "Allen",
            order: "order2"
        }
        ],
        group: {
            field: "number"           
        }
    }
});
```

The code below could display the combined field, but there're two problems:
1. The header text always contains 'header:' prefix, such as "header:number:1,name:Jane Doe";
2. In the column filter, there's a header column in it.

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "number",
        hidden: true
    },{
        field: "name",
        hidden: true
    }, {
        field: "order"
    },{
        field: "header",
        hidden: true
    }
    ],
    dataSource: {
        data: [{
          number: 1,
            name: "Jane Doe",
            order: "order1",
            header: "number: 1, name: Jane Doe"
        },
        {
          number: 1,
            name: "Jane Doe",
            order: "order2",
            header: "number: 1, name: Jane Doe"
        },
        {
          number: 1,
            name: "Jane Doe",
            order: "order3",
            header: "number: 1, name: Jane Doe"
        },{
          number: 2,
            name: "Allen",
            order: "order1",
            header: "number: 2, name: Allen"
        },{
          number: 2,
            name: "Allen",
            order: "order2",
            header: "number: 2, name: Allen"
        }
        ],
        group: {
            field: "header"           
        }
    },
    columnMenu: true
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce this scenario in a snippet? That'd help us fix the issue for you. There's not much we can do with just a description.

Comment: @Cerbrus, thanks for your reply, please see my code in the post. the data grouped by number, and all the name in the group are the same, so I want to hide the name field, and let it display in the group header. Such as "number: 1, name: Jane Doe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide column description from the group header you should use groupHeaderTemplate: "#= data.value #".

To hide column from ColMenu you should use "menu": false in your column definition.

The column wiht both changes applied should look like:

```
    {
       field: "header",
       hidden: true,
       "menu": false,
       groupHeaderTemplate: "#= data.value #",
    }
```

Comment: It looks like I need to loop the the whole data source for every record, it may introduce performance issue. Is there any other way? In my post, I write a solution, but not work well, is there away to hide the introduced header column in column filter and hide the "header:" prefix in my code?

Comment: use groupHeaderTemplate: "#= data.value #"

Comment: thanks, this solve the second issue, but how to fix the first issue? the combined field will display in columns filter, is there a way to hide it?

Comment: you ca hide it using function columnMenuInit(e) {}

Comment: sorry, could your provide more details?

Comment: please igore last comment use: {
        field: "header",
        hidden: true,
       "menu": false,
    }

Comment: columnMenuInit is fired when the menu is initialized and there you can perform dynamic hiding etc. if it's a static hide you can use the above example